# The most efficient way to convert a 2D array of duplicate names each with unique value to 2D array with unique names with multiple values, in PHP?

Tags: php

What is the most efficient way to convert an array like this:

```
[ [ 'Quiz 1' , 89 ] , ['Quiz 2' , 78] , ['Quiz 1' , 56] , ['Quiz 1' , 25] , ['Quiz 2' , 87] , ['Quiz 3' , 91] ]
```

to this:

```
[ [ 'Quiz 1' , 89, 56, 25] , ['Quiz 2' , 78, 87] , ['Quiz 3' , 91] ]
```

in PHP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterating in a foreach loop is the most *efficient* way to do it, if you mean the best-performing. It may not be the most elegant way. You could also use `array_map` or other such; for each their preference. In any case, by using the Quiz number as a grouping key. Here's for the simples:

```
$vars = [ [ 'Quiz 1' , 89 ] , ['Quiz 2' , 78] , ['Quiz 1' , 56] , ['Quiz 1' , 25] , ['Quiz 2' , 87] , ['Quiz 3' , 91] ];

$grouped = [];
foreach($vars as $var) {
    empty($grouped[$var[0]]) && $grouped[$var[0]] = [$var[0]]; // If Quiz # must go in.
    $grouped[$var[0]][] = $var[1];
}
```

Output:

```
Array [
    [Quiz 1] => [
        [0] => Quiz 1
        [1] => 89
        [2] => 56
        [3] => 25
    ]
    [Quiz 2] => [
        [0] => Quiz 2
        [1] => 78
        [2] => 87
    ]
    [Quiz 3] => [
        [0] => Quiz 3
        [1] => 91
    ]
]
```

You will notice that the values are grouped with Quiz # as a key. (Necessary.) Making the first entry in the array redundant. If you don't need the in-array Quiz number, comment out the first line of the loop. If you need it and don't like the Quiz numbers used as keys, finish up with `$grouped = array_values($grouped);` to revert to a plain numerical index.

Comment: This is a fantastic solution. Thank you

Comment: Cheers. There may be more complicated ways of doing this, but for that we'll have to wait for the experts. ^_^

Comment: Its seems you are the expert here @MarkusAO!  Awesome solution!